# "Re-declared Defined Without Usage" One Script but Not The Other?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This sounds like it should be blindingly obvious but there's something quirky going on.

So I have two scripts. Largely the same but a few variances here and there. They both run big loops and they both use global variables. Yes, I know this is bad. Tidying it up is on my to do list but I'm on a time constraint at the moment.

One script works fine. As expected.

The other works fine... for the most part. Then it bugs out once it iterates through the loop again. It's very strange because the code has very little differences but I did pick up on something which I can't explain.

The variable I use to track my position in the loop is set like this in script 1 (which works flawlessly):

```
global CurrentMatchScan
while True:
    print "=Starting Loop="
    Loopcounter = 0
    CurrentMatchScan = -1
    LoadMatch()
```

The second script has:

```
global CurrentMatchScan

while True:
    print "=Starting Loop="
    Loopcounter = 0
    CurrentMatchScan = -1
    LoadMatch()
```

However in the second script PyCharm highlights the = -1 part as

```
Redclared'CurrentMatchScan' defined above without usage
```

So the obvious assumption is something further up in the code is using it. I do call a function later on which is placed up there...

```
def LoadMatch():
    nextbox1 = LinkList[CurrentMatchScan + 1]
    nextbox2  = LinkList[CurrentMatchScan + 2]
```

But this is only called once CurrentMatchScan is set... and the first script has the exact same code.

Is my IDE just not noticing it on the other script or something? There's a pretty big issue with the looping on the second one and this is the only difference I can see between the two.

I know this doesn't look like a lot to go on but there's not much else to it that I can see. It's barely actually referenced.

I'd really appreciate anyone who can point out how much of an idiot I'm being and missing something really simple.

/edit:

Based on the fact that it does use CurrentMatchScan and calls LoadMatch() for the first iterations properly I'm starting to doubt this is anything but PyCharm trying to warn me I'm potentially doing something silly.

I think if this was the issue it wouldn't work at all so the warning might be a bit of a red herring when it comes to the issue I'm actually facing.

Comment: I think we need more context. Try removing all fluff (e.g., start with removing the `LoadMatch()` call) until the essential part that causes the error remains; that should be a relative modest amount of code to post. By then, you may well have tracked down the problem yourself.

Comment: A typo somewhere may also be the problem.